# IBM MobileFirst - Problems connection database Java Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Good morning,

I have a Java Adapter and a REST method try to make a SQL query, but I have a right error in this line: `Connection con = ds.getConnection ();`

The error is as follows:

> [6/17/15 10:05:51:577 CEST] 00000076
>   com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox E FWLSE03030E: Error during
>   handling Java Adapter request (see logs) [project
>   IBMConfirmingProject] java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   com.confirming.ws.rest.MyAdapterCustomerResource.getTotalFact(MyAdapterCustomerResource.java:89)

In the lib (server) folder, I have the jar: mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
And in the file server.xml I have the following configuration:

```
<library id="MySQLLib">
  <fileset dir="C:\Desarrollo\Java\juno-4.2.2\workspace5\MyProject\server\lib" includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar"/>
</library>

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/mobilefirst_training">
  <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib"/>
  <properties databaseName="mobilefirst_training" password="mobilefirst" portNumber="3306" serverName="localhost" user="mobilefirst"/>
</dataSource>
```

The log also shows the trace:

[ERROR] FWLSE03030E: Error during handling Java Adapter request (see logs) [project IBMConfirmingProject]
java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters 1105" at ffdc_15.06.17_11.57.08.0.log
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ibm.confirming.ws.rest.MyAdapterCustomerResource.getTotalFact(MyAdapterCustomerResource.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Thanks,

Comment: In server.xml i have the datasource configurations

Comment: Provide the full server logs.

Comment: [6/17/15 10:05:51:592 CEST] 00000126 com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox E FWLSE03030E: Error during handling Java Adapter request (see logs) [project IBMConfirmingProject]
java.lang.NullPointerException at ibm.confirming.ws.rest.MyAdapterCustomerResource.getTotalFact(MyAdapterCustomerResource.java:89) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you will follow the Java SQL adapter instructions as written in the tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/java-sql-adapter/.

Specially, try keeping the reference to the MySQL connector as-is: `<fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}" includes="mysql-*.jar" />`

Place the file here:
[image]

Comment: I knew the tutorial, but have not resolved the problem, thanks anyway, I will continue investigating

Comment: You need to provide your code. The way you have implemented the adapter and the way you're calling the adapter. Your problem is likely there.

Comment: I just saw, I lacked MyAdapterCustomerResource.init (); in MyAdapterCustomerApplication, thank you very much

Comment: @Eladerezador, Please write this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw, I lacked MyAdapterCustomerResource.init (); in MyAdapterCustomerApplication, thank you very much